# Xhr request errors are not getting logged on New Relic platform

Tags: javascript, next.js, newrelic

I have integrated New Relic into one of my NextJS application and I'm also able to get some of the JavaScript related errors like reference error on New Relic platform.

Though New Relic is not logging any xhr related errors on their platform. Got 403 Forbidden, 404 Not found and 500 internal server error on my network calls but New Relic did not reported any of those.

I have used the following steps for the setup:

1. Added a script code for the same in a new added file as public/js/newrelic.js. Some of the code is mentioned below:

```
;window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.init={distributed_tracing:{enabled:true},privacy:{cookies_enabled:true},ajax:{deny_list:["***"]}};
;NREUM.loader_config={accountID:"***",trustKey:"***",agentID:"***",licenseKey:"***",applicationID:"***"}
;NREUM.info={beacon:"***",errorBeacon:"***",licenseKey:"***",applicationID:"***",sa:1}
```

2. Added the script tag to run the same script code in my project
   `<script async type="text/javascript" src="/js/newrelic.js" />`

I have checked on their docs and different online available resources for xhr related errors but got no help.

What can I more use to get xhr related errors. In case, if it is not possible, let me know that as well.

Answer (score 0):

We do include 404 requests, it’s part of the ajax requests page

If XHR is missing — do you see the requests being sent in ingest? here’s a doc of the endpoints: [https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/relic-solution-understanding-bam-nr-data-net-data-transmission-its-endpoints/58535  Also](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/relic-solution-understanding-bam-nr-data-net-data-transmission-its-endpoints/58535%E2%80%A8%E2%80%A8Also)

It looks like it's loading the agent as a external file, which can work but is unsupported: Added the script tag to run the same script code in my project     Script should load inline, in the  tag and be the first script on the page.

If the script is loaded asynchronously then it is very likely that some requests would be missed. Only after the script has initialised and wrapped the XHR and Fetch native functions would we capture any requests using them, so any made prior to that (even if not completed) would be missed.